# Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, adobe, mxml

I'm using flex 4 to build a program and I am getting this error on one module I call.

```
Error #1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

Does this refer to the module document (.mxml) or the actually xml file the module it calling?

Comment: Have you tried running in debug mode?  Do you have code to share?  Is this a run time error or a compile time error?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ? What did you do ? Can you please post your solution here as answer

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely XML *content* you're loading, not the module.  If the MXML file had issues, you'd hit them at compile-time, rather than run-time.

Can you post the XML file you're loading?

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I answer for the sake of solution.

There can be 2 answers:

- The XML is not well formed (load it in a browser)
- The XML file is not found, but still an event is fired and you try to convert to XML("null");

Answer (score 0):

Run the XML content that you're loading in through an XML validator like this - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

It's possible you simply have a type somewhere in your XML, and if you validate it it'll find it for you and tell you where it is.

Comment: Great tool, I just tested it out. No errors with the xml but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one root element in an XML file.
Could it be that you have multiple roots?